# How to calculate points for twist?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, secp256k1

How I can find the point to perform this twist attack - https://cryptodeep.ru/twist-attack/

English version of previous link:

https://github.com/demining/Twist-Attack

This video has additional information - https://youtu.be/fBY9Q2DxcLE

I have the RSZ signature, but how do I calculate points from the signature for a twist attack as is shown in the above link?

Example of point:

`Q11 = E1([34618671789393965854613640290360235391647615481000045539933705415932995630501, 99667531170720247708472095466452031806107030061686920872303526306525502090483])`

point Q11, from this base point and curve:

`p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

`E1 = EllipticCurve(GF(p), [0,1])`

`P11 = E1([85121563011366687025707822879925964033143920255507899862530934382179124106759, 42409656727948788569510737393982221864295921023467166630061319157315739523945])`

`ord11 = 20412485227`

What data from the signature do I need to multiply to E11 to get point Q11?